# Failed to start WinNAT service

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, nat

How Resolved this problem ?

I try make switch using a nat network.
(from this link: https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2016/05/set-up-a-hyper-v-virtual-switch-using-a-nat-network/ )

I made:

`New-VMSwitch –SwitchName “NAT_vSwitch” –SwitchType Internal`

`New-NetIPAddress –IPAddress 172.100.100.1 -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (NAT_vSwitch)"`

but when I make this line:

`New-NetNat –Name NetworkNAT –InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 172.100.100.0/24`

My Output in PowerShell looks like:

`New-NetNat : Failed to start WinNAT service
At line:1 char:1
+ New-NetNat –Name NetworkNAT –InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 172.100 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetNat:root/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetNat) [New-NetNat], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1168,New-NetNat`

what I am doing wrong or where I should looking for error?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.
Firstly, backup the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi
```

Then proceed to delete the items with the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nsi\{eb004a00-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}.
```

In powershell, then perform:

```
start-service WinNat
```

If it is able to start, then try your command again:

```
New-NetNat –Name NetworkNAT –InternalIPInterfaceAddressPrefix 172.100.100.0/24
```